# Log4net create new custom eventlog , but log into the Application log only

Tags: c#, multithreading, log4net, event-log

config is

```
 <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
  <applicationName value="MyService.exe" />
  <LogName value="MyLogs" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%level %thread (%file:%line) %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="LOGGER">
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
</logger>
```

- Log4net create new custom eventlog "MyLogs", but log into the Application log with Source "MyService.exe".

How I can to say log4net log into my new custom eventlog "MyLogs" ?

Comment: Remember only a process running with administrative rights can create an event source - see [Why doesn't the EventLogAppender work?](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#trouble-EventLog) in the docs for details.

Comment: Yes - of course, but as I wrote custom eventlog "MyLogs" already created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in config in key

```
<applicationName value="MyService.exe" />
```

there should be like

```
 <applicationName value="MyLogs/MyService.exe" />
```

- and all working well !

By [default](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_EventLogAppender_LogName.htm) log4net log into the Application log - so we need add path for our custom log.